# How to make a binary decomposition of pandas.Series column

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to decompose a `pandas.Series` into several other columns (number of column = number of values), save that factorization and use it with other `DataFrame` or `Series`. Something like `pandas.get_dummies` which will remember mapping and can handle `NaN`.

Example.
Given the following `DataFrame`:

`A  B
0  a  0
1  b  1
2  a  2
3  c  3`

I want to have a decomposition of series `A` into:

`A_a  A_b  A_c  B
0    1    0    0  0
1    0    1    0  1
2    1    0    0  2
3    0    0    1  3`

Then I want to save that factorization and apply it to other `DataFrame` (look input doesn't have *c* values in column A):

`A  B          A_a  A_b  A_c  B
0  a  0       0    1    0    0  0
1  a  1   ->  1    1    0    0  1
2  b  2       2    0    1    0  2`

Is there any automatic way for such thing? I can do it manually.
I was trying [scikit-learn LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder) but it doesn't handle `NaN`s. I want to use it for classification models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this automatically:

```
In [11]: res = df.pop("A").str.get_dummies()  # Note: pop removes column A from df

In [12]: res.columns = res.columns.map(lambda x: "A_" + x)

In [13]: res
Out[13]:
   A_a  A_b  A_c
0    1    0    0
1    0    1    0
2    1    0    0
3    0    0    1

In [14]: res.join(df)
Out[14]:
   A_a  A_b  A_c  B
0    1    0    0  0
1    0    1    0  1
2    1    0    0  2
3    0    0    1  3
```

---

To standardize, I would use `reindex_axis` on the columns you want. i.e. to force df2 to have the columns of df1.

```
df2.reindex_axis(df1.columns, axis=1, fill_value=0)
```

Comment: As wroted in the question - I know about `get_dummies` - but this doesn't resolve my problem to apply the same mapping to the other series object. You don't need to use `map` on columns - `get_dummies` have an optional parameter `prefix`

Comment: Is reindex_axis not what you're after?